# numpy.nan to int shows different results on 2 computers

Tags: python, numpy

I am facing a very strange problem with `numpy` using this MWE:

```py
import numpy
print(numpy.array(numpy.nan).astype(int))
```

- On my Mac Pro (2019), macOS 12.2.1, **Python 3.9.10** and **numpy 1.22.2**, the result is `-9223372036854775808` (smallest `int64` value).
- On a Debian 10, **Python 3.7.3** and **numpy 1.21.4**, the result is `-9223372036854775808`
- On my MacBook Air (M1, 2020), macOS 12.2.1, **Python 3.9.10** and **numpy 1.22.2**, the result is `0`.

As far as I remember, `numpy` used to throw an error when trying to convert `numpy.nan` to `int`. This behavior seems to have changed, but the result is inconsistent.

Is there a reason for this behavior? Is it possible to ensure that `numpy` behaves the same on every machine? I can't find anything in the doc about this behavior.

Comment: Could you show the versions of numpy you are running on your systems ?

Comment: I am using 1.22.2 on both system.

Comment: probably a bug on M1 processer. open up a bug with numpy and see what they have to say

Comment: I have just open an issue, thanks!

Comment: This is not a bug of the M1 processor. I get the same result (-9223372036854775808) on Linux with Numpy 1.20 with no error. To me, this may be an *undefined behavior* in the implementation. We discussed about this problem recently but so far no decision has been taken (mainly because we did see consistent results in internal Numpy tests). Thank you for reporting this issue.

Comment: I get -9223372036854775808 on every machine I have tried so far, except on the M1 chip I have where I get 0.

Comment: This is dependent of the hardware architecture. On x86-64 machine, it *should* be the minimum possible int value, but on other processor like ARM or POWER it can be something else. If you need a workaround (waiting for this to be solved in Numpy), you can filter/check the result with `numpy.isnan`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and the explanations! I am using a workaround for now, but I have to skim through the entire project to fix this --'